# low stock notification to admin without any extension in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, module, custom, inventory

I want to create the custom module for email sent to admin for notifying when the product is low qty in magento 1.9.x.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can do it using cron jobs what you have to  do is create a cron job and in its function you need to load the whole products and check which product has low stock you can set limit like only those product which has only 10 QTY left you can get their sku in an array once you have an array of sku then you can send the details in mail to your admin.
Benefit of using cron job is you can set timings like you can check product stock in every 2 days or 3 days according to you.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this module for Magento low stock notification**

https://github.com/geekster909/magento-low-stock-notification

Comment: I fixed Notify for Quantity Below 5 and I change the qty is  2 in inventory option by admin panel of the product and also write down the email id in mail option in observer.php but still, I am not getting any mail...please help

Comment: simple `mail()` function is enabled on your server ?